# Replacing main menu item by submenu items via css?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I've written a simple **vertical menu** like:

```
Home  Information  Info
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to replace a list element with it's own sublist when the item is active. I'm trying replace `Home` with `Sub1` and `Sub2` when the item is active in order to modify the navigation as follows:

```
Sub1 Sub2 | Information  Info
```

Is there a way to achieve this via css?

---

#### Markup

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Home Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home Sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>

    <li><a href="#">Informations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
ul.nav {
  float:right;

}

ul.nav > li {
  border:1px solid #333;
  display:block;
  float: left;
  line-height:38px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
  padding:20px
}


ul.subnav {
    display:none;
}
```

---

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4zpdpg7/17/)

Comment: Do you want something [like this DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/u4zpdpg7/18/)?

Comment: Great! Thanks. For the sake of completeness: Is it possible to get vertical elements when clicking the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to put `.subnav` element inside a `li` element, like:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="with-subnav"><a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Home Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home Sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Informations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in your CSS code:

```
ul.nav > li.with-subnav:hover > a{
    display:none;
}

ul.nav li:hover ul.subnav{
    display:block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/u4zpdpg7/18/)

**Update**:

Maybe you want the elements horizontally with this:

```
ul.subnav li{
    float: left;
}
```

[**DEMO2**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/u4zpdpg7/19/)

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

Solution that solved the problem finally, was to concatenate both classes (`active` and `with-subnav`). [**Check the DEMO here**](https://jsfiddle.net/u4zpdpg7/20/) :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this should solve my issue. I'll check if it also works with an active element instead of a hover.

Comment: I ended up with concatenate both classes (`active` and `with-subnav`): https://jsfiddle.net/u4zpdpg7/20/ in order to make it work - feel free adding this to your answer if you like... Thanks again!

Comment: Of course, already UVed :) Since I'm asking for *Replacing* and not on *Hovering*, the answer is maybe a bit of for future visitors, might be a good idea to add the current solution to your answer, but I can also add it to my question if you don't like it for any reason... What do you think?

Comment: I thought your comment was enough for future visitors. But your solution was also added to the answer. Happy coding!